# "a decision on / about where to go"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which preposition is more appropriate?

> No decision has been made ____ where to go on our holiday yet.

Is it a) **on** or b) **about**?

<sub>This sentence is from an English language text book for Italian teenagers. The sentence cannot be modified.</sub>

Some websites tell me that  a decision can be **on** or **about**, but I'm not entirely sure in the example above.

*[Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/decision)* and [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/decision) suggest that either can be used

> **decision about/on**
>
> - *We finally came to a firm decision **on** the matter*.
> - *The decision **about/on** whether he is innocent or guilty rests with the jury.*

Whereas *[Common Mistakes in Business English](https://blog.harwardcommunications.com/2021/02/02/decide-to-decide-on-and-make-a-decision/)* appears to give *on* the upper-hand.

> “Decide on” is followed by a verb in the –ing form or a noun / noun phrase.
>
> - “We **have decided on** the purchase of our company’s competitor in Florida.”

*[Oxford Learner’s Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/decision)* appears to agree

> We need **a decision on** this by next week

From the net I found examples of “decision about where”

- You can’t make a decision ***about*** *where* to go to university?
- Universities ask for varying amounts of points based on their entry requirements, so this will help you make a decision ***about*** *where* to apply.
- Once you have received all of your offers and visited any institutions you are thinking about attending then it is time to make your decision ***about*** *where* you want to go.

and examples of “decision on where”

- Helping Your Aged Parents Make A Decision ***On** Where* to Live
- How can you make a decision ***on** where* to go? How much does it cost to study abroad, and what are the student visa requirements?
- BIRMINGHAM, England, Oct 5 (Reuters) - British Prime Minister Theresa May said the British government would soon make a decision ***on** where* to build extra airport capacity in southeast England.

---

If both prepositions are acceptable is there a slight difference in meaning?
A decision is made after you have thought about it, so shouldn't "I'm thinking *on* where to go" be also grammatical?  Of course, the correct version is "I'm thinking *about* where to go” but I can't explain why "about" fits. Likewise, I can't explain why “…a decision on where…” sounds better to me.

Comment: Both are acceptable. [see google ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+decision+about+where%2C+a+decision+on+where&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). There is a minor difference in meaning. **About** has more a sense of: **on the subject of**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (1) No decision has been made on where to go on our holiday yet.
> (2) No decision has been made about where to go on our holiday yet.

Both are grammatically valid. A fluent speaker would understand, and might well say or write either.  I think I might favor (2), just to avoid the repetition of "on" that occurs in (1).

In other uses of "a decision on" or "a decision about", I think the first is more likely to be used for a specific choice, often a yes/no choice, or a choice from a limited set of options; while the second for a more general decision in the area of the subject. But I would not assert this as an absolute rule, or an inference that can safely be drawn from such use in the absence of context.

Comment: @Ronald Sole Thanks, got those also.